# Team-sport play data, in particular ball passes

Tags: data-request, sports

I am looking for game-play data of any team sport which include ball passes between players and who passed the ball to whom. Ideal games include (with order of importance) basketball, handball, football (soccer), lacrosse, rugby, American football, hockey. Volleyball is not acceptable because it limits the number of passes.

Comment: You might also try Sports SE. To the extent that datasets exist, they may not be part of "Open Data."

Answer (score 1):

[1]: http://goalserve.com provide live sports like Soccer, NFL,NBA,MLB,College,NFL, PGA,Cricket.They XTL feed include live player stats, play by play, season team stats, fixtures and past season data.

Comment: is that open data? clicking on a link fires off a new ad tab, seems like spam